# Wave pulse animation in svg format

Tags: svg

I want to create a signal pulse SVG animation like [this](http://www.vibrantcomposites.com/) at middle of pages.

Is there any animation creation program to generate something like that with SVG output?

Comment: Just draw a path with Snap or Raphael etc, and animate scaling it out, repeat. Have a bash and post some code on a jsfiddle if you get stuck.

Comment: I made the path http://jsfiddle.net/cybercoder/vvj2npr4/ but i have no idea how to flow pulse signal the wave line.

Comment: You can use the dash offset tricj (https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/) to animate your pulse. But first, you will need to fix your path. The path will need to be one continuouse path. But yours is made up of three individual paths.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I did that http://jsfiddle.net/vvj2npr4/4/ , But how i can flow a dashed line on the path, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the dash offset trick.  Make the dash pattern a short line followed by a long gap.  Then animate the dash offset so that the "pulse" line starts before the line and finishes after it.

```css
#wave {
    stroke-dasharray: 50 520;
    stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    animation: dash 1.5s linear;
}

@keyframes dash {
    from {
        stroke-dashoffset: 50;
    }
    to {
        stroke-dashoffset: -520;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 184.36846 109.46607"
     height="109.46607"
     width="184.36845">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <path id="wave" style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#595a5c;stroke-width:3.3132751;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="M 1.1007072,52.963103 C 22.852586,52.155573 16.43834,66.286629 17.978217,84.883612 30.593999,58.36225 27.407458,29.665987 33.938472,2.697475 39.165571,33.060386 36.265426,75.55841 36.323337,106.7143 L 47.146958,41.038775 c 2.988779,6.354218 2.039353,53.463638 8.989108,53.751201 2.884138,-0.04301 3.118671,-8.071852 3.118671,-8.071852 0.869781,-6.707612 0.753109,-33.811575 8.622206,-34.488826 C 106.26973,51.33495 144.68349,51.884499 183.0843,52.045847" />
  </g>
</svg>
```